# Call stack exceeds in quick sort function

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I'm doing an exercise for school trying to write my first Quick Sort. It's sorting an array of random integers. When I call it, I get a "call stack exceeded" error. Is anyone able to point to my mistake(s)?

```
const quickSort = (unsorted) => {
    //let median = Math.floor(Math.random() * unsorted.length -1);
    let median = Math.floor(unsorted.length -1 /2);
    let greater = [];
    let lesser = [];
    let sorted = [];
    
    if(unsorted.length < 2) {
        return unsorted;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < unsorted.length; i++) {
        const element = unsorted[i];
        const pivot = unsorted[median]
        if (element > pivot) {
            greater.push(element)
        } else {
            lesser.push(element);
        }
    }
    
    let sortedLesser = quickSort(lesser);
    let sortedGreater = quickSort(greater);
    sorted = [...sortedLesser, ...sortedGreater];
    return sorted;
}
```

Comment: First thing I see is `unsorted.length - 1 / 2` is the same as `unsorted.length - 0.5`.

Comment: Even if you add parens as @calculuswhiz hinted, your `median` will be 0 for an array of length 2, resulting in the `greater` array never shrinking less than 2. It should be `median = Math.floor(unsorted.length / 2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea of QuickSort is that the pivot element is excluded from the recursive calls. This way you can be absolutely sure that recursive calls will always get a smaller array, even if the pivot was located at an extreme end of the original array.

As noted in comments your division by 2 only applied to 1 (since division has precedence over subtraction), meaning that your pivot index was always the last index in the array. And as you did not exclude that index from the recursive calls, you get a recursion tree that never shortens the array.

I would suggest the following changes:

```
const quickSort = (unsorted) => {
    let median = unsorted.length >> 1; // 1 bit shift is integer division by 2
    let greater = [];
    let lesser = [];

    if (unsorted.length < 2) {
        return unsorted;
    }
    const pivot = unsorted[median]; // Do this once only
    for (let i = 0; i < unsorted.length; i++) {
        if (i === median) continue; // exclude the pivot itself
        const element = unsorted[i];
        if (element > pivot) {
            greater.push(element)
        } else {
            lesser.push(element);
        }
    }

    let sortedLesser = quickSort(lesser);
    let sortedGreater = quickSort(greater);
    // Include the pivot here
    sorted = [...sortedLesser, pivot, ...sortedGreater];
    return sorted;
}
```

Although this corrects the issue, please realise that Quick Sort is intended to not create extra arrays, but reorder the original array *in place*.